# search conditions between dates

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

```
HTML
<input id="UserID" class="textbox" type="text" size="1" name="UserID" value="<%= Server.HtmlEncode(UserID) %>">
<input type="text" name="Startdate" style="width:100; height:19" size="20" id="datepicker" class="textbox" value="<%=StartDate%>">
<input type="text" name="Enddate" style="width:100; height:19" size="20" id="datepickerExp" class="textbox" value="<%=EndDate%>">
```

ASP

```
UserID=request.querystring("UserID") 
startdate = request.Form("startdate")
enddate = request.Form("enddate")
```

SQL

```
strSQL= "SELECT * FROM  Report WHERE UserID LIKE '%" & UserID & "' and DatePO BETWEEN ( '"&startDate&"', 106) AND ('"&endDate&"', 106)"
```

but it can not run
hope people help me write the sql to be able to find data on the conditions.

respect

Comment: We would need to know a load more, like what DB you are using, how the tables look, what error you are getting etc... **very unlikely** that people can actually help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

If your database is MySQL, try use STR_TO_DATE(column, 'data_format')

I use this date format in my applications (format date used in Brazil) '%d/%m/&Y', but you can modify according of your application.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing ideas. First at All, you need to *tag your html elements in a Form*.

Then you have to decide how you pass your values to the server (**POST or GET**).

If you decide to pass them by **GET method**, you will recover them, in server-side, using **request.querystring**.

If **POST method** is choose, you have to use **request.Form**.

Finally, I recommended you to debug your code for checking if you are recovering the values from client in a proper way in the server. After that you can start to think what are you doing wrong.

Comment: I've revised the declaration with server HTML

Comment: Could you show us the actually sqlString and the error coming from it?